# How to prevent useSelector from causing unnecessary renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I'm using `useSelector` hook to retrieve the values of my reducer, but it is causing a lot of unnecessary renders on my application.

It doesn't matter which property I'm using on a component, since they are all getting the same `state` object from the reducer, every time one property changes, all components that use `useSelector` are rendered.

This is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
   productsDataState: [], // => this is populated by multiple objects
   searchProducts: [],
   isSearchOn: false,
   inputValue: '',
   listOrder: [],
   toastify: ['green', ''],
   toastifyOpen: false
}

const reducer = ((state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.UPDATE_PRODUCT:
         return {
            ...state,
            productsDataState: action.products,
            listOrder: action.listOrder
         }
      case actionTypes.SET_TOASTIFY:
         return {
            ...state,
            toastify: action.toastify,
            toastifyOpen: action.open
         }
      case actionTypes.SET_SEARCH:
         return {
            ...state,
            searchProducts: action.searchProducts,
            isSearchOn: action.isSearchOn,
            inputValue: action.inputValue
         }
      default:
         return state
   }
})
```

One of the components is using `isSearchOn`, which is a boolean, so I solved the problem checking if the value is `true` before rendering it:

```
 const { isSearchOn } = useSelector(state => state.isSearchOn && state)
```

But that's not the case for all components. The one I'm stuck right now uses the `productsDataState` property, which is an array of objects. I can't just make a simple validation before returning `state`. I thought about storing the initial value in a `useState`, make a deep comparison between the current value and the past one before returning the state, which would work similarly to what I did in the other component, but I can't see how this would be a good approach.

```
const { productsDataState } = useSelector(state => state)
```

Is there a way where I could take advantage of `useSelector` without comprimising the performance of the application?

I've being reading a lot and making a lot of tests, but I couldn't find a good way to do that so far.

I'd like to keep `useSelector`, but I'm open to suggestions, even if it involves other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should be doing is not selecting whole state, just the part you need :)

```
const productsDataState = useSelector(state => state.productsDataState)
```

@edit

If you want to select multiple data with one selector you will cause it to change reference if you would try to use an object for example.

```
const { productsDataState, other } = useSelector(state => ({ productsDataState: state.productsDataState, other: state.other }))
```

this will cause rerender on any state change as redux use strict equality check by default.

You should listen to [official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) and select each state separately

`Call useSelector() multiple times, with each call returning a single field value`

Comment: I see. So, if I'm using multiple properties I should use a useSelector for each one? Isn't a way where I could destructure it and prevent the render?

Comment: answered in edit :)